# Graph API features

Tags: java, javascript, facebook-graph-api

What features does Facebook's Graph API support? I have already incorporated publishing messages.

Can I get:

1. Online list of friends.
2. Chat
3. Profile Pictures

Answer (score 1):

This [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) shows all the things that can be accessed.

All objects in Facebook can be accessed in the same way:

Users: https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor (Bret Taylor)

Pages: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola (Coca-Cola page)

Events: https://graph.facebook.com/251906384206 (Facebook Developer Garage Austin)

Groups: https://graph.facebook.com/2204501798 (Emacs users group)

Applications: https://graph.facebook.com/2439131959 (the Graffiti app)

Status messages: https://graph.facebook.com/367501354973 (A status message from Bret)

Photos: https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305 (A photo from the Coca-Cola page)

Photo albums: https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305 (Coca-Cola's wall photos)

Profile pictures: http://graph.facebook.com/100000990755826/picture (your profile picture)

Videos: https://graph.facebook.com/614004947048 (A Facebook tech talk on Tornado)

Notes: https://graph.facebook.com/122788341354 (Note announcing Facebook for iPhone 3.0)